# MvxExpandableListAdapter SetItemsSource is not called

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have this code snippet to using `MvxExpandableListView`

```
public class ExpandView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ExpandView);
        MvxExpandableListView list = FindViewById<MvxExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.TheExpandView);
        list.SetAdapter(new MyCustomAdaptor(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext));
    }

    private class MyCustomAdaptor : MvxExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private IList _itemsSource;
        public MyCustomAdaptor(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(context, bindingContext)
        {
        }

        protected override void SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
        {
            Mvx.Trace("Setting itemssource");
            if (_itemsSource == value)
                return;
            var existingObservable = _itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (existingObservable != null)
                existingObservable.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

            _itemsSource = value as IList;

            var newObservable = _itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (newObservable != null)
                newObservable.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;

            if (value != null)
            {

            }
            else
                base.SetItemsSource(null);
        }

    }
}
```

When the view is loaded the override method **SetItemsSource**  does not get called , but when I try to navigate away from the page  **SetItemsSource**  gets called with a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `ItemsSource`.Looking at the source of `MvxAdapter`:

```
[MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
public virtual IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return _itemsSource; }
    set { SetItemsSource(value); }
}
```

The setter of `ItemsSource` calls the method `SetItemsSource`.

`MvxExpandableListAdapter` inherits `MvxAdapter`.

**Source:**
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Views/MvxExpandableListAdapter.cs
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Views/MvxAdapter.cs

Comment: i have already set the itemsource in the xml  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource xyz"